# What should I do about (poorly-written, but) on-topic question about outdated software?

Tags: discussion

I came across this question [Running old version of android studio issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980681/running-old-version-of-android-studio-issue) in First Posts review queue. It asks for help with dated version of Android Studio, that is from 2015 year.

Best advice that can be given to author is to find a better tutorial and use fresh version.

But the question looks on-topic, although useless for future readers. What should I do with it?

Comment: I fail to see how it being an older version of a product makes it any worse as a question.  Address the problems in the question unrelated to its version (of which there are plenty for you to address).  If you also want to comment on the question telling them that they might have better experiences with a newer version, you are of course free to do so.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891)

Comment: What makes it worse as a question is that the fix is many times to simply run the current version of the software.  Of course, it's not always possible for a variety of reasons, but step 1 of troubleshooting is "are you on the current versions"...

Comment: @Servy ...If it's an old, unused version, it's useless. That doesn't make it off-topic or poorly written, but it does make it a bad question, because it won't help future visitors. Note that I said "unused" -- not all old versions of things are unused.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Given that someone is using it (the person that's asking the question) clearly it's *not* unused.  Questions about versions of a product that are *unusable* (i.e. old versions of a product requiring servers from the company to run that are no longer running it) are of course useless, but products that are less commonly used but entirely usable are not useless.  They might be *less* useful than newer versions, but that doesn't make them useless.

Comment: As a follow-up to Servy's comment, Even if something appears unusable, like the server case Servy mentioned, if a person is making a question about it, then they must have found a way to use at least some part of it, and if one person has found a use for it, it is very likely that there is at least one other person who has found that same use.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Actually, if people ask questions about an old version X, then it means that version X **is in fact used**. whether only 10,1 or 0.001% of the users of that software use version X is irrelevant.

Answer (score 37):

Upvote/Downvote depending on the normal reasons for voting. Just being an old software version doesn't change the validity of the question, and it still might be useful.

Sometimes people are stuck working with old, out of date technology, perhaps because their manager at work is too cheap to request an update to their machines, or because they're working on an old product that won't support newer software, or a dozen other reasons. Just because it's outdated doesn't mean nobody uses it, so the questions are valid.

I personally can't think, in the case of that question, why a person would be forced to work with an outdated version of Android Studio, but I'd be willing to give him or her the benefit of the doubt and say possibly this answer might be useful to someone, but I'm certain that there are at least a handful of people still using the 2015 version for whatever reason.

Of course, as always questions should be well asked and follow all normal question-asking rules, so if the person has written a good, well presented and well researched question, upvote it. If it's poorly written, just like any other question, downvote it.

Comment: Definitely the part about being stuck with old outdated software. Been there...

Comment: This is not really applicable to mobile. The mobile *operating systems* drop old technology pretty quickly. Trying to resist upgrading is business suicide because your customers will soon be running devices that won't run your application (either because they got new ones or because they upgraded the OS to keep up).

Comment: @jpmc26 even if it's true in mobile, I think that rules/code of conduct should be site wide and not tag-specific.

Comment: @SamJudge It isn't a question of rules. It's a matter of whether the question is useful, which is relevant for downvoting.

Comment: @jpmc26 I completely disagree. The practical benefit of the potential answers to a question should have no bearing on upvoting/downvoting, just that the question is well asked and not a duplicate. An answer will at the very least be useful to the person who asked the question in the first place, and that is enough usefulness IMO.

Comment: @SamJudge SO set out use a Q&A format as a community wiki, not create an individual help service for all comers. The latter is not sustainable at any reasonable level of quality; see the Slashdot effect.