# Is "can no longer be reproduced" a close reason for a question about an old software?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Is the close reason "can no longer be reproduced" also meant for questions about old versions of tools/frameworks/software?

The description is:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Does *no longer* mean, that a question should/could be closed if there exists a newer version solving the problem?

Examples:

- [Copy from ansible empty folder on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382479/copy-from-ansible-empty-folder-on-remote-server)
- [Getting ACEGI_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381834/getting-acegi-saved-request-key-null)

Comment: Related: [What should I do about on topic question about outdated software?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361102/what-should-i-do-about-poorly-written-but-on-topic-question-about-outdated-so/361104)

Comment: Is it important to stop answers from being added to a problem that no longer exists?  Closing a question is useful if it happens very early or if it attracts too much spam.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't vote to close such questions, but I saw it happen and that's the reason for my question.

Comment: Forgot to look a the linked questions, they fit the "early" category.  The one that actually got closed is the handiwork of a chat room.  Voting rings are not exactly my personal favorite approach to moderation, but they are impossible to stop and appear to be condoned.  Consistency tends to be the victim, in an ideal world [a question about software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17-bit-and-35-bit-integers) that has been obsolete for 60 years ought not to get 28 votes :)  These are "don't bore us with trivial stuff" votes.

Answer (score 16):

Is it literally impossible for anyone to ever use the version of the product that the question is asking about, and is the question only applicable to that version?

If so, then yes.

If not, then no.  Just because a newer version exists doesn't necessarily mean that no one is ever able to use the older product, or that the question isn't also applicable to the newer versions.

Comment: *Is it literally impossible for anyone to ever use the version of the product that the question is asking about* Could you give an example?

Comment: @dur Well, it's pretty rare for that to ever be the case.  Perhaps questions about the facebook API when the API features in question are no longer supported (I don't know if they have ever had breaking changes, but hypothetically if they did).  In such a case a question asking about the earlier behavior *can no be seen by anyone*, because the service running the API has changed and no longer behaves that way.  A question about, say, an earlier version of C++ or an old version of Windows is obviously something that someone can still actually be using.

Comment: Thanks, Facebook's REST API is a good example.

Comment: @dur not necessarily, unless the problem was specific to that api. Not all facebook rest api questions are that.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, that's what Servy wrote: *and is the question only applicable to that version*.

Comment: @dur: On the client side, an example I always refer to is [pre-release versions of Internet Explorer that were set to expire, have expired, and no longer run on any machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340761/ms-animation-should-i-include-this-for-older-browsers/42341302#42341302). Tons of CSS remains on production sites going *completely unused* and wasting bandwidth because it depends on versions of IE that don't even run anymore.